# Symbol size in Legend

Tags: legending

I am making a simple plot with a legend:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, PlotStyle ->Red, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[{Style["data 1", FontSize -> 20]},
  LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> White, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]] &)],
  Scaled[{0.9, 0.15}]]
]
```

How to change the size of the symbol in the legend? 
I am using Mathematica 10.0.2.

Comment: Look up `LegendMarkerSize`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option setting `LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 20}`:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[{Style["data 1", FontSize -> 20]}, 
    LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 20}, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> White, 
        FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]] &)], 
   Scaled[{0.85, 0.15}]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can specify the `PointSize` in the first argument of `PointLegend`, e.g., using

```
PointLegend[{Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}, {Style["data 1", FontSize -> 20]}, 
 LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> White, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]] &)]
```

in the code above gives

[image]

Comment: If I do `SetOptions[PlotLegends, LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 20}]` then I get an error `LegendMarkers is not a known option for PlotLegends. >>`. So, how to handle `LegendMarkers` in Options?

Comment: @Luigi, `PlotLegends` does not have any options. You can try `SetOptions[PointLegend, LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 20}]` . This should work (but it doesn't in version 9).

Comment: it does not work, also in version 10.0.2

Comment: do we see workarounds?

Comment: @Luigi, a workaround is to use `SetOptions[PointLegend, LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 40}]` and `PlotLegends -:>PointLegend[....,  Options[PointLegend]]`